# equality of sets of MOD-strings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logic, algebraic-number-theory

Let q be a prime number and let $t$ have $q$ as a prime divisor.
For each prime number $p$ define the set of strings  $MOD_p:=\{a_1 \dotsc a_n \in \{0,1\}^{\ast}: \sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i \equiv 0 \,(mod\,p)$} and let $MOD_{l,k}:=\{a_1 \dotsc a_n \in \{0,1\}^{\ast}: \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \equiv k \,(mod\, l)\}$ for $0 \leq k < l$.

Then $MOD_q = \bigcup\limits_{c=1}^{t/q} MOD_{t,cq}$.

I don't understand why this holds (besides that the upper limit $t/q$ doesn't fit in with the definition and perhaps is a little error), so I'd be glad if anyone could explain to me why this equality does hold.

[For those interested, this stems from the book Finite Automata, Formal Logic, and Circuit Complexity, page 149.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an error.

$MOD_q$ consists of the (finite) strings with a multiple of $q$ ones. If $t$ is a multiple of $q$ (say $t=mq$) then clearly any string in the right hand side has $cq+rt = cq+rmq$, for some integer $r$, a multiple of $q$ so it is in $MOD_q$.

On the other hand if a string in $MOD_q$ has $uq$ ones then writing
$$ u \equiv c \pmod{m}$$
for some $1 \leq c \leq m $, we see that the string has $cq+rmq = cq+rt$ ones for some integer $r$ so it is en $MOD_{t,cq}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Esteban! Now I understand the equality. :) 
With error I meant the upper limit $t/q$: In the definition of $MOD_{l,k}$ it says $k < l$. But if $c$ equals $t/q$ there is $MOD_{t, t}$ in the union and t isn't smaller than t...?

Comment: I mean, shouldn't go the limits from $c = 0$ to $(t-1)/q$?

Comment: @Studentu Yes you are right. I think the $0\le k < m$ in the definition of $MOD_{k,q}$ can be modified also, it depends on how the concept is used later.

Comment: Okay, thanks Esteban!